# How to use OAuth2 for CLI?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am building client and server application to work together. Both applications are built using node. The server app will be hosted, and client app will be available to users for download. For authentication I decided to use OAuth 2.

According OAuth specification it involve client entity which consist of client id and client secret. I understand why and how that should be used in term of web service where user grant access to specific website, but I don't understand how that should feet in CLI app where both could be accessible to any user.

For my perspective it makes no sense to hardcode client id and client secret somewhere in the code. Could someone explain me how that should work for that kind of applications?

Comment: You definitely lack the idea of different OAuth2 flows. The auth code flow that involves both client id and secret is not suitable for command line apps.

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After struggling few days and reading RFC, finally  pieces came to my mind. In my case the correct flow is password grant. For anyone else who need to make similar decision, which flow to use, I can recommend reading this explanation:

http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/

Comment: The password grant is now deprecated and will be removed in OAuth 2.1: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/